# python gtk window not responding

Tags: python

I process a new function and append the values from new function to the gtk window till the second function completes, the window gets unresponsive and can become responsive when second function completes.

can anyone tell me what should i do for the same?

Comment: Can you share the code ? That would be helpful to detect issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gobject.idle_add](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--idle-add) to have a function be executed and still keep your windows responsive.